# Is it possible to force ParallelDo to periodically close and launch subkernels?

Tags: parallelization, memory

I have a function `f` which calls an external library that has a memory leak, so I kind of have to live with it.

I call this function thousands of times within `ParallelDo` and each subkernel eventually blows up in memory. I'd like to have `ParallelDo` close a subkernel when 'too much' memory is being consumed, and then have it launch a fresh subkernel.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

A naive workaround is to chunk the `ParallelDo` calls within a `Do` loop and close & relaunch manually.

i.e. turn `ParallelDo[f[k], {k, n}, Method -> "FinestGrained"]` into

```
kcnt = 8;
chunk = 48;
Do[
  LaunchKernels[kcnt];
  (* my calls to DistributeDefinitions, etc. *)
  ParallelDo[f[k], {k, chunk*j+1, Min[n, chunk*(j+1)]}, Method -> "FinestGrained"];
  CloseKernels[];
  {j, 0, Floor[n/chunk]}
]
```

A problem with this solution is that one call to `f` can be very slow, and so all other calls over `chunk*j+1` to `Min[n, chunk*(j+1)]` will finish and so we wait for a single call to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code, not very elegant but should work and hopefully is easy enough to understand so that it probably is good enough as a starting point:

```
numkernels = 2;
numcalculations = 10;
maxcalcsperkernel = 3;
evaluations = {};
calccounts = <||>;
results = Table[Null, {numcalculations}];
calccount = 0;

LaunchKernels[numkernels];
f[k_] := (Pause[RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]]; k^2);
DistributeDefinitions[f];

While[Count[results, Null] > 0,
  While[
    And[calccount < numcalculations, Length[evaluations] < numkernels],
    calccount++;
    Print["submit: ", calccount];
    With[{cidx = calccount},
      AppendTo[evaluations, ParallelSubmit[{$KernelID, cidx, f[cidx]}]]
    ];
  ];
  {{kid, cidx, res}, finished, evaluations} = WaitNext[evaluations];
  Print["kernel finished: ", kid];
  results[[cidx]] = res;
  calccounts[kid] = Lookup[calccounts, kid, 0] + 1;
  If[And[
      calccount < numcalculations, 
      calccounts[kid] >= maxcalcsperkernel
    ],
    Print["restart: ", kid];
    CloseKernels[kid];
    calccounts = KeyDrop[calccounts, kid];
    LaunchKernels[1];
  ];
]; 
CloseKernels[];
results
```